# How to access SyncResult from Android Activity

Tags: android, synchronization, android-activity, android-syncadapter

I have a `SyncAdapter`, which uses the `SyncResult` `SyncStats` to pass information back to the Android `SyncManager`, during a sync e.g.:

```
public void onPerformSync(final Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
   final ContentProviderClient provider, final SyncResult syncResult) {

...

++syncResult.stats.numInserts;
... 

}
```

It would be useful to have access to these stats in my `Activity` so that I can display some of them to the user. How can I get access to the `SyncResult` `SyncStats` from my `Activity` when a sync is complete? Is there a way to do this?.

**Edit:** Or would it be best to do this via normal Service to Activity comms (e.g. `AbstractService.send()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would send a Broadcast at the end of synchronization with the sync stats you require parsed into broadcasted intent's extras. You can even use a sticky broadcast, but beware of its [perils](http://porcupineprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/09/android-sticky-broadcast-perils.html) :)